# Парсинг текста с таблицей в словарь

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Мне нужно распарсить текст в ключ:значение, и чтобы это было универсально, если текст будет меняться, правильно и лучше сделать через регулярку, но я не особо в ней разбираюсь, и прошу помощи тут. Вот пример возможного текста (получается путем 'show variables like '%password%';' в sql). Я и сам почти смог сделать, но не могу пустые значения никак учесть

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+

+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name                 | Value                 |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
| server_audit_events           | CONNECT,QUERY,TABLE   |
| server_audit_excl_users       |                       |
| server_audit_file_path        | server_audit.log      |
| server_audit_file_rotate_now  | OFF                   |
| server_audit_file_rotate_size | 1000000               |
| server_audit_file_rotations   | 9                     |
| server_audit_incl_users       |                       |
| server_audit_logging          | ON                    |
| server_audit_mode             | 0                     |
| server_audit_output_type      | file                  |
| server_audit_query_log_limit  | 1024                  |
| server_audit_syslog_facility  | LOG_USER              |
| server_audit_syslog_ident     | mysql-server_auditing |
| server_audit_syslog_info      |                       |
| server_audit_syslog_priority  | LOG_INFO              |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Пытался сделать вот так, и по списку сделать словарь, но теряется пустое значение, и вот сижу думаю, никак не придумаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не надо изобретать лисапед - сразу получайте значения в переменные из sql.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне именно так парсить нужно

Comment: что на выходе вы хотите увидеть - регулярка вам вернет значение левого столбца и правого для одной строки скажем - `| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |` вы получите `validate_password.policy` и `MEDIUM` - вам это надо? регулярка работает со строками, так что скажем `8` тоже будет строкой и вы сами должны ее в число переводить

Comment: Мне не нужно ничего переводить, мне нужно сделать словарь, чтобы ключами было то, что слева, а значениями, что справа. Я не могу никак сделать так, чтобы пустое значение тоже было.
Должно получиться типа:
{'Variable_name': 'Value',
'validate_password.check_user_name': 'ON',
'validate_password.dictionary_file': '',
'validate_password.length': '8',
и т.п}.
И для этого решил взять регулярку, чтобы избавиться от всего лишнего и сделать универсальный код, так как мне не только этот текст такого формата надо парсить

Comment: Можно для пустого значения захватывать 1 пробельный символ и в коде проверять это - https://regex101.com/r/Rw2MI5/1.

Comment: Сможешь пожалуйста написать полностью, а не только шаблон ?) Чтобы я результат получил

Comment: @Vladimir если вы мне, то по этой ссылке слева есть `Code Generator`, который генерит питоновский код.

Answer (score 2):

не понятно, зачем вам регулярка, если можно просто сплитить:

```
d = dict()
for i in info.split("\n"):
    if not "+--" in i and len(i):
        res = i.split("|")
        d[res[1].strip()] = res[2].strip()
```

правда,  заголовок попадает в словарь тоже, но с этим, думаю, вы разберетесь.
d:

```
{'Variable_name': 'Value', 'validate_password.check_user_name': 'ON', 'validate_password.dictionary_file': '', 'validate_password.length': '8', 'validate_password.mixed_case_count': '1', 'validate_password.number_count': '1', 'validate_password.policy': 'MEDIUM', 'validate_password.special_char_count': '1'}
```

Comment: Это будет работать только для этого текста. Обновил вопрос с следующий текстом

Comment: "это" будет работать для любого текста. если же вы хотите сказать, что в тексте у вас может быть несколько таблиц, то я обновил код.

Answer (score 0):

потестируйте такую регулярку:

```
from re import findall

dict(findall(r'\| (.+?)\s*\| (.+?)\s*\|',text))

>>> out
{'Variable_name': 'Value',
 'server_audit_events': 'CONNECT,QUERY,TABLE',
 'server_audit_excl_users': ' ',
 'server_audit_file_path': 'server_audit.log',
 'server_audit_file_rotate_now': 'OFF',
 'server_audit_file_rotate_size': '1000000',
 'server_audit_file_rotations': '9',
 'server_audit_incl_users': ' ',
 'server_audit_logging': 'ON',
 'server_audit_mode': '0',
 'server_audit_output_type': 'file',
 'server_audit_query_log_limit': '1024',
 'server_audit_syslog_facility': 'LOG_USER',
 'server_audit_syslog_ident': 'mysql-server_auditing',
 'server_audit_syslog_info': ' ',
 'server_audit_syslog_priority': 'LOG_INFO'}
```